# Blender Missing library. Fails to start

Tags: blender

Can someone help?

```
$ blender
blender: error while loading shared libraries: libavcodec.so.54: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory


$ apt-cache policy blender
blender:
  Installed: 2.76.b+dfsg0-3build1
  Candidate: 2.76.b+dfsg0-3build1
  Version table:
 *** 2.76.b+dfsg0-3build1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

$ lsb_release  -a
LSB Version:    core-2.0-amd64:core-2.0-noarch:core-3.0-amd64:core-3.0-noarch:core-3.1-amd64:core-3.1-noarch:core-3.2-amd64:core-3.2-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution

```
# Install the libavcodec-extra package using apt-get package manager.
```

$ sudo apt-get install libavcodec-extra-56

## Verify the location of libavcodec.so.54 file path.

$locate libavcodec.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavcodec.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavcodec.so.56
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavcodec.so.56.1.0

## Create a new ldconfig file with proper path to the shared library.

$ sudo nano /etc/ld.so.conf.d/blender.conf

## Add the following line in the file.

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/

## Rerun ldconf

$ sudo ldconf

## Start blender normally.

$ blender

https://playingwithsid.blogspot.com/2016/08/blender-missing-shared-library-gotcha.html